# POST in firestore DB using only API Key as Auth

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, postman, firebase-security

in my firebase I set as authentification "Anonym" and want to try a POST to my firestore using the project API key as follow:

```
POST /v1/projects/myproject123-62cd3/databases/(default)/documents/sammlung2/test321 HTTP/1.1
Host: firestore.googleapis.com
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer apikey3123idsn3ejhsd3
Content-Length: 111

{
  "fields": {
    "field1": { "stringValue": "value1" },
    "field2": { "stringValue": "value2" }
  }
}
```

Firestore rules are:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow write, read: if request.auth.uid == 'API_KEY';
    }
  }
}
```

As response I get "Request had invalid authentication credentials.". What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to post to Firestore with the API key of your project. The bearer token in the `Authorization` header has to either be the ID token of a Firebase Authentication user, or the OAuth2 token for a collaborator on the project.

Also see the Firebase documentation on [authentication and authorization with the REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/use-rest-api#authentication_and_authorization) for Firestore, which says:

> For authentication, the Cloud Firestore REST API accepts either a [Firebase Authentication ID token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/) or a [Google Identity OAuth 2.0 token](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2).

Comment: thanks, this clarifies my problem! :)